# removing duplicates from a list python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [IM12345, IM12346, IM12347, IM12348]
list2 = [ID300, ID404, ID300, ID601]
```

`list2` associates with the corresponding `list1` values. `list1` has unique values where as `list2` has duplicates.

I want to make `list2` unique corresponding associated value will add in the that `list2` value.

```
Dict= {ID300: {IM12345, IM12347}, ID404: IM12346, ID601: IM12348}
```

Above pattern can be in list, set or dictionary.

Which algorithm in python should I use to get the above result?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)

list1 = ['IM12345', 'IM12346', 'IM12347', 'IM12348']
list2 = ['ID300', 'ID404', 'ID300', 'ID601']

for key, value in zip(list2, list1):
    d[key].add(value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'ID300': {'IM12345', 'IM12347'}, 'ID404': {'IM12346'}, 'ID601': {'IM12348'}})
>>>
>>>
>>> for i, j in d.items():
...     print(i, j)
...     
... 
ID601 {'IM12348'}
ID300 {'IM12345', 'IM12347'}
ID404 {'IM12346'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict to save the dataset

```
list1 = ["IM12345", "IM12346", "IM12347", "IM12348"]
list2 = ["ID300", "ID404", "ID300", "ID601"]

dictResult=dict()
i=0
for item in list2:
    print item
    if dictResult.has_key(item):
        dictResult[item].append(list1[i])
    else:
        dictResult[item]=[list1[i]]
    i=i+1

print dictResult
```

Result:

```
{'ID404': ['IM12346'], 'ID300': ['IM12345', 'IM12347'], 'ID601': ['IM12348']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not completely be a pythonic way but - here it goes:
Map the input:

```
map = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Now you can do an inverse mapping:

```
inv_map = {}
for k, v in map.iteritems():
    inv_map[v] = inv_map.get(v, [])
    inv_map[v].append(k)
```

Result for the example above:

```
>>> inv_map
{'ID404': ['IM12346'], 'ID300': ['IM12345', 'IM12347'], 'ID601': ['IM12348']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it could be with list operations.

```
yourList = ["1","2","3","4","1","2"] 
newList = [] 
for f in yourList:
    if f not in newList:
       newList.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = ['IM12345', 'IM12346', 'IM12347', 'IM12348']
list2 = ['ID300', 'ID404', 'ID300', 'ID601']

d = defaultdict(list)

for n in range(len(list2)):
    d[list2[n]].append(list1[n])

print d.items()
```

Result:

```
[('ID404', ['IM12346']), ('ID300', ['IM12345', 'IM12347']), ('ID601', ['IM12348'])]
```

[Python2.7 Documentation----defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)